# ReactJS application add bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I've just installed `bootstrap 4` by `yarn add` and I have problem with using components which use javascript, because they need `jQuery`. My question is where is `webpack` file to add files linked with `jQuery` and `Proper` ? I'm using to start project `create-react-app` cli.

Comment: Why not use [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) directly, no need to import jquery.

Comment: I use react-snapshot, when files are compiled to static HTML version for examplem baner slider don't work.